# Web2py return json or redirect

Tags: redirect, web2py

In web2py, I want to set up a controller that redirects for an html view but provides a json response for a json view, e.g.

http://mysite/page.html/1234 -> redirects to http://www.google.com/q=mydata
http://mysite/page.json/1234 -> returns JSON {'1234':'my data'}

(this example assumes I have a db query that returns 'mydata' for id=1234)

I can't immediately see how to do this, as the redirect() function is called in the controller, but the decision about json or html seems to be made later, once a dict() is returned from the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you can use `request.extension` to decide whether to  `redirect()` or `return response.json(my_data)`.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that you can set {{redirect('http://site/{}'.format(data))}} in the .html view, and it will do a proper redirect within the html file itself (and set the correct content headers). In other words, the redirect function doesn't need to be called in the controller, if that's easier.

Comment: That is contrary to the MVC principle as implemented in web2py.